# Finding the average of numbers in an array

Tags: java

I have an array of *test grades* for each *student* in a class. As an example, for Adam *test1=90 test2=92 test3=93*, so the average would be *91.67*. I would then save this as `Array6`. Then using that array, I would take *30%* of that plus *70%* of the final (`array5`) to make new array `courseaverage`.

I have tried to implement this in my code below, but it doesn't work correctly. Could anyone please suggest the problem...

```
public class Proj5 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {        
        String[] Array1 = {new String ("Adam"),new String ("Smith"),new String ("Jones"),new String ("Becky"),new String ("Taylor")};       
        Integer[] Array2 = {new Integer(90),new Integer(89),new Integer(86),new Integer(76),new Integer(95)};        
        Integer[] Array3 = {new Integer(92),new Integer(79),new Integer(85),new Integer(90),new Integer(87)};
        Integer[] Array4 = {new Integer(93),new Integer(80),new Integer(90),new Integer(87),new Integer(92)};
        Integer[] Array5 = {new Integer(90),new Integer(77),new Integer(86),new Integer(92),new Integer(89)};

        System.out.println("Name Test1 Test2 Test3 Final Average Grade");

        for (int column = 0; column<Array1.length; column++){
            System.out.printf("%s ", Array1[column]);
            System.out.printf("%s   ", Array2[column]);
            System.out.printf("%s    ", Array3[column]);
            System.out.printf("%s    ", Array4[column]);
            System.out.printf("%s  ", Array5[column]);
            System.out.println(); //start new line of output
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give you a hint: If you can't figure this out on your own, your next test score will be zero.

Comment: Another hint:  If the prof gave you the list of numbers on a piece of paper (along with maybe a simple 4-function calculator), how would you figure the average?

Comment: `int [] array5 = {90, 77, 86, 92, 89}; ` would be too simple?

Comment: Try to do it with just one array containing all the grades for a student. After try with different arrays as you have in your assignment. It is *just* playing with variables in your loop structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array does not have a get() method but an ArrayList does so if you change your arrays to ArrayLists then you can use get() to retrieve the value.

If I understand correctly you have an array that holds the names of each student and each student's grades are held in a seperate array for each student?

```
String[] students= {"Adam","Smith","Jones"}; 
int[] adamGrades = {90,92,93};
double gradesTotal = 0.00;
for(int i=0; i < adamGrades.length; i++){
  gradesTotal += adamGrades[i];
}
double avg = (gradesTotal/adamGrades.length);
System.out.print(avg);
```

That would give you the average for "Adam" and you should be able to use that to figure out the rest of your problem.

Comment: I have to use array and not ArrayLists so how would I go about doing it this way? It would be simple with list but yeah..

Comment: Theres a array that stores names then a array that stores test 1 grades, another for test2. They dont store the grades for a person otherwise this would be easy :p

Comment: I guess a better question would be is there something similar to the get() method from arraylists for arrays? if so I could just take value 1 from array added to value 1 form array 2, same for three then just div by 3 to get the average? Then take these into new array

Answer (score 1):

To not give away the exact answer (since this is homework) you need to take the array, add up all the elements and divide that sum by the number of elements in the array.  This could be done easily in a function call accepting the array and returning the average.

Comment: How would I do this since I have to pull one number from each array, for example Adam I would have to get first in array1, first in array2 and so on

Comment: One way you can do this is add all the individual arrays into a new array to make it all into a multi-dimensiona (2D) array.  Then you can iterate over all columns by row or rows by column.